# How to not include an empty string in the icontains condition in model filter?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm currently developing an application using `Django`.

If I use the `filter` of the `model` and set the target of `icontains` to the `empty string` `″` as shown below, all the data is gotten.

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(my_field__icontains='').all()
```

But I don't want to include it in the data if the `icontains` target is an `empty string`.

How can I enable it only if it does not include the `empty string` and contains other values?

---

Python: 3.7.5

Django: 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check the target:

```
if target:
    queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(my_field__icontains=target)
else:
    queryset = MyModel.objects.none()
```

Comment: thank you for your help, actually I want to use it in multiple conditions using `Q`. so I made another post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70815676/how-to-not-include-the-data-from-db-in-the-multiple-icontains-condition-in-model