# How to not include the data from DB in the multiple icontains condition in model filter?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm currently developing an application using `Django`.

I want to use multiple `icontains` condition in `filter` using `Q` as shown below.

but in this case, If either `target_1` or `target_2` is an `empty string`(`''`), all the data is gotten.

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(my_field_1__icontains=target_1)| Q(my_field_2__icontains=target_2)).all()
```

But I don't want to include it in the data if the value of either target becomes an empty string.

How can I enable it only if they do not include the empty string and contains other values?

---

Python: 3.7.5

Django: 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with dictionary comprehension to filter out empty values:

```
data = {'my_field_1__icontains': target_1, 'my_field_2__icontains': target_2}
data = {k: v for k, v in data.items() if v}

if data:
    queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(**data, _connector=Q.OR))
else:
    queryset = MyModel.objects.none()
```

the `if data` checks if there is at least one item with a non-empty string. If that is not the case, we return an empty queryset.